Filter out pull requests with changes requested
I receive dozens of pull requests per week on GitHub, and review each of them over the weekend.
Often I request changes, making the pull request appear like this (notice the Changes requested part):

Question: How to make such pull requests not appear in my search?
-review:changes-requested does not seem to work:
https://github.com/commons-app/apps-android-commons/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen+-review%3Achanges-requested++-is%3Adraft+-status%3Afailure+
By the way I also use -is:draft to only review pull requests that are ready, and -status:failure to only review pull requests that do not break continuous integration.

The correct syntax is: -review:changes_requested
Full URL to focus on pull requests worth reviewing:
https://github.com/commons-app/apps-android-commons/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen+-is%3Adraft+-status%3Afailure+-review%3Achanges_requested
